# Как получить значение Retry After если его нет в headers запроса Python

Tags: python, requests

Делаю парсер на get/post запросах и приходится перебирать очень большое количество ссылок. Всё нормально работает, но в какой-то момент получаю ошибку значений словаря. Поискал в чём дело, оказалось что я скорее всего превышаю количество допустимых запросов за определенное время. Нашёл решение, в котором нужно получать значение Retry After у заголовков запроса. Но проблема в том, что этого Retry After в них нет. Вот всё что получаю:

```
{'Server': 'nginx', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=90', 'Expires': 'Fri, 09 Apr 2021 16:20:44 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Fri, 09 Apr 2021 16:18:00 GMT', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Content-Length': '2544', 'Date': 'Fri, 09 Apr 2021 16:20:04 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Есть ли какой-то способ "вызвать" Retry After или как по-другому избежать данной проблемы? Сейчас обернул код в While True с try - except внутри. Это работает, но мне кажется что должно быть какое-то более правильное решение. Так же максимально важна скорость выполнения кода, поэтому ставить задержки через time.sleep() или нечто похожее не вариант. Извиняюсь, если непонятно написал так как было сложно объяснить в чём дело. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Насколько я понял, этот заголовок приходит при 503-м статусе ответа. Когда вы ошибку получаете какой у вас статус ответа приходит? И смотрели ли вы на заголовки в этот момент? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764075/retry-after-http-response-header-does-it-affect-anything

Comment: А может и не только 503: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After

Comment: @CrazyElf ошибка 429. Читал, по результатам схожа с 503-м. Заголовки, которые я прикрепил это и есть заголовки при ошибке

Comment: Ну, если сервер не возвращает ничего, значит там не настроено

Comment: @CrazyElf а как тогда правильно избежать данную ошибку? Может есть какое-то среднее значение, которое обычно ставят в значение Retry After. Или можно как-то ещё это сделать. Просто спустя время код выходит из цикла и опять начинает работать, но на само ожидание нужно тратить время, а мне нужно максимально ускорить скрипт. Или лучше тогда ставить задержку перед каждым запросом?

Comment: Ну я не знаю. Это только следить за поведением сайта и пытаться угадать что именно он ограничивает. Число запросов за некий промежуток времени? Кто ж его знает.